# Server Error in '/' Application after submitting a form

Tags: forms, http-status-code-405, server-error

New to coding here...  Just got my validation form working, now after submitting the form, I am getting a Server Error in '/' Application after submitting form. This type of page is not displayed.

```
    <form action="ContactUsResults.cshtml" method="POST">
```

When I change my page type to .htm

```
    <form action="ContactUsResults.htm" method="POST">
```

Then I get the 405 error message 'Method Not Found'

Ideally, I am just trying to get to a confirmation page after they submit the form.

Thanks!

Comment: The form action should be an actual file on the server. In this case, you've asked it to look for two different files: one with the extension .cshtml and the other with just .htm. Do either of these exist? It's also looking in the same directory as the file it's being called from since you haven't specified otherwise.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it both ways (I don't have both form actions in the code together, just showing for example)  When I have tried it either the cshtml or htm way, I made sure I had the corresponding file in the same directory.

Comment: Where is your code hosted? "405 errors often arise with the POST method. You may be trying to introduce some kind of input form on the Web site, but not all ISPs allow the POST method necessary to process the form." - http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E405.html

Comment: I am using WebMatrix to build my site.  It is not hosted anywhere yet.  I am just testing the form validation and submission.

Comment: I'm not familiar with WebMatrix - are the files you're creating running on your local machine or in the cloud? You are encountering a server error (405 is a status code similar to the familiar "404: File Not Found" we all know from web browsing)

Comment: My files are all local.

Comment: I have posted the correct answer, but without more information on what web server is running on your local machine I can't give much advice about how to enable the POST method. This is a web server configuration issue and not a problem with your script.

Answer (score 0):

The web server that is running as part of your WebMatrix environment is not configured to allow the POST method, hence the 405 "Method Not Found" error. You will need to enable the POST method in settings or a configuration file in order for your form action to work.